# Making user not to delete any web part

Tags: 2013, web-part

I have a web part zone page where user can add web part.

I want to display a particular document library in that page which user shouldn't be able to edit or delete.

Basically I don't want to give "Add a webpart" option to user and he should not be able to modify existing or add new web part in that page except that document library which I have already added, so he should only be able to upload documents and other related functions only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a web part directly to a page or to a page layout without a web part zone then the users will not be able to change or remove that web part.

Comment: And how do I do that? By adding it directly in page layout i SharePoint designer? But that means I won't be able to use the same page layout on other pages, right!?

Comment: Yes that is correct - if you add a web part to a page layout then it would appear in all pages using that page layout.